# flask, mod_wsgi, apache: Importerror:

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

I am having an issue deploying a flask app on apache2 using wsgi. I guess i have already tried every solution proposed on this site, but nothing has helped. Every input or suggestions are appreciated.

Here are my files and logs

**apache conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi D:/microblog/test/wsgi.py
<Directory D:/microblog/test>
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import sys
from test import app as application


sys.path.insert(0, 'D:/microblog/test')
```

**_*init*_.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile("app_config.py")
app.debug = True 

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "hi"

app.run()
```

**apache log**

```
[Wed Apr 09 09:52:27 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=3368): 
Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'D:/microblog/test/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 09 09:52:27 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call     last):
[Wed Apr 09 09:52:27 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "D://microblog/test/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
[Wed Apr 09 09:52:27 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from test import app as application
[Wed Apr 09 09:52:27 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: cannot import name app
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use WSGIPythonPath directive in Apache configuration to tell mod_wsgi where your project code is. Don't know your code structure, but try:

```
 WSGIPythonPath /microblog/test
```

Comment: Did you try the obvious and add the driver specifier I managed to leave out. In other words, you may need to adjust the value you set it to as I can't guess your directory layout. Indicate what path you ended up setting it to and what directory your app.py file or app directory is located.

Comment: yes i have added the driver specifier but it isn't still working. I guess the error lies in the wsgi.py, but i cant find and fix it.